# bower-rails not removing packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

I am using bower-rails gem in my rails app. It works fine. But I can see that when I remove a package from Bowerfile and run `rake bower:install` its not removing as expected. Isn't it the way to remove packages when using bower-rails?

**Bowerfile**

```
asset 'bootstrap-sass'
# START_HIGHLIGHT
asset 'angular-resource'
# END_HIGHLIGHT
asset 'angular', '~> 1.5'
resolution 'angular', '1.5'
asset 'angular-ui-router'
asset 'normalize-css'
asset 'angular-bootstrap'
asset 'flexslider'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake bower:install` doesn't remove packages, running `rake bower:update:prune` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that..But its still not removing..Did that works for you?

Comment: I deleted all and cloned a new one from repo and now its working..dont know what happened before.